# Confilct in SQL Server version

Tags: ssms-2012, ssms-2014

I know that `SELECT @@version` gets the version of server.

But when SSMS booting, it shows SQL Server 2014.

[image: SSMS booting]

I want to know what original version of SSMS what I am using.

**UPDATES 1**

As per `Antonio Campagnaro`'s answer, I got more confusion. See below image

[image: Help->About]

Comment: Version 12 of SSMS was released with MSSQL Server 2014

Comment: @AntonioCampagnaro oh..I'm using `'14` Server and `'12` SSMS. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is a program that can connect to a sql server instance. If you need to know what SSMS you are using you can find it in Help -> About..

If you need to know what sql server instance version you are using you can query `SELECT @@VERSION`

SSMS and sql server doesn't need to be the same version, but SSMS need to be higher than sql server

[Other way to get sql server version](https://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/what-version-of-sql-server-do-i-have/)

Comment: SQL Server = database engine; SQL Server Management Studio = GUI Administration Tool for working against the SQL Server engine [hope this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273903/microsoft-sql-server-vs-sql-server-management-studio)